# Creating unique random ID

Tags: java

Would this create a unique user ID for [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/)?

```
Build.BOARD.length()+"" + Build.BRAND + Build.DEVICE + Build.DISPLAY.length() % 10
 + Build.HOST.length() % 10 + Build.ID.length() + Build.MANUFACTURER.length() % 10 
 + Build.MODEL.length() % 10 + Build.PRODUCT.length() % 10+ Build.TAGS.length() % 
 10 + Build.TYPE + Build.USER.length() % 10;
```

Comment: Have you tried running it? What results did you get?

Comment: If you're not confident in your id generation, you probably should just use an existing algorithm

Comment: If what you want is a universally-unique identifier, do not re-invent the wheel. Use a [universally unique identifier (UUID)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). See the [Answer by WJS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62626824/642706).

Answer (score 2):

## UUID

Did you consider using a [universally unique identifier (UUID)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) such as that returned by [`UUID.randomUUID()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID())?

```
UUID s  = UUID.randomUUID();
System.out.println(s);
```

Prints something like

```
d918666e-6ebb-4700-99fe-c3279ba2daff
```

Additional UUID methods are also available.  But no guarantees it would be unique.  Just an *extremely* high probability that it is.

Comment: FYI, today I learned about the [Version 6 UUID proposed addition](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-peabody-dispatch-new-uuid-format-00) to [RFC 4122](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122). This version reorders the bits of a UUID value to better facilitate indexing in databases. An open-source implementation can be found in the [*UUID Creator*](https://github.com/f4b6a3/uuid-creator#uuid-creator) project.